# How to reindex AWS Elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

My Ruby/Sinatra app connects to an AWS ES cluster using the [elasticsearch-ruby gem](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby) to index text documents that authorised (by indexing using their user ID) users can search through. Now, I want to copy a document from one index to another to make a document query-able by a different, authorised user. I tried the _reindex endpoint as documented [on this file](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/reindex.rb) only to get the following error:

> Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Unauthorized - [401] {"Message":"Your request: '/_reindex' is not allowed."}:

Googling around, I stumbled across an Amazon docs page that lists all supported operations on both their API's, and for some twisted reason _reindex isn't there yet. Why is that? More importantly,
how do I get around this efficiently and achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should double check the Elasticsearch version deployed by AWS ES. The `_reindex` API became available in [version 2.2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html) I believe. You can check the version number by GETting the ES root ip & port with curl e.g. and checking version.number.

To work around not having the `_reindex` endpoint, I would recommend you implement it yourself. This isn't too bad. You can [use a scroll](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/scroll.rb) to iterate through all the documents you want to reindex. If it is the entire index, you can use a matchall query with the scroll. You can then manipulate the documents as you wish or simply use [the bulk api](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb) to post (i.e. reindex) the documents to the new index.

Make sure to have created the new index with the mapping template you want ahead of time.

This procedure above is best for reindexing lots of documents; if you just want to move a few or one (which it sounds like you do). Grab the document from its existing index by id and [submit it](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/index.rb) to your second index.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elasticsearch now supports remote reindex, check this documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/remote-reindex.html

Example below:
'''

```
POST <local-domain-endpoint>/_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "https://remote-domain-endpoint:443"
    },
    "index": "remote_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "local_index"
  }
}
```

'''

Comment: The link has several examples, it is straight forward and does not require whitelisting any URL as standard Elasticsearch requires.